# How to get the quadrant for a given inequality

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I am trying to find the quadrants for the following question:

> In the rectangular co-ordinate system, which quadrants contain at
> least one point $(x, y)$ that satisfies the inequality:
>
> $$2y > \dfrac x5$$
>
> $(A.) \\$ I 
> $(B.)\\$ II 
> $(C.)\\$ III 
> $(D.)$ IV

How do I go about it ?

Comment: Can you explain what you have tried so far? Like have you tried to plot $f(x)=x/10$ and see if there are any $(x,y)$ pairs where $y>f(x)$?

Comment: @AbdullahAliSivas I’ve tried putting in quadrant wise points in the equation, like $(2,3)$ for 1st quadrant, (-2,3) for 2nd quadrant and so on. And then checking if each point satisfies the given inequality. Is it the right approach ?

Comment: The Demonix Hermit already provided the answer. Analytical approach to solve these problems is to reduce them to another problem, in this case an inequality check i.e. when $y>x/10$ is true. If $y<0$ and $x>0$, this inequality cannot hold so you can eliminate the fourth quadrant. Check the answer below for other quadrants.

Comment: @AbdullahAliSivas Yes, it was a wonderful explanation indeed. However, can I tackle the problem by the approach I mentioned above ?

Comment: That would work if you want to show existence of such a point. However, you can not eliminate the fourth quadrant that way. "I tried bunch of points and couldn't find any which satisfies the inequality" is not a good argument. Maybe you missed that one single special point, who knows. So you need a rigorous argument. One explanation I provided is an example, it appeals to the fact that all negative numbers are less than positive numbers by construction, so there are no pairs $(x,y)$ in fourth quadrant such that $y>x/10$.

Comment: @AbdullahAliSivas Yeah you’re right. I should boil it down to the basics. In this case the simple nature of positive and negative number. Thanks a lot for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$2y\gt \dfrac x5 \implies 10y \gt x$$

If $x,y$ in $1$ quadrant , $x,y \gt0$ there exists many $x,y$ with the desired property.

If $x,y$ in $2$ quadrant , $x\lt0 , y\gt 0$ there exists many $x,y$ with the desired property.

If $x,y$ in $3$ quadrant , $ x\lt 0 , y\lt 0$ there exists many $x,y$ with the desired property.

If $x,y$ in $4$ quadrant ,$x\gt 0 , y \lt 0$ there do not exists any $x,y$ with the desired property.

So the answer is $1,2,3$ quadrants.

Comment: Yeah this seems right. I was confused for the third quadrant. But it seems if you take a point in the range of -0.1 for y and -2 for x, it would satisfy the inequality.